# Identity matrix with the total differential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $U \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $f: U \to \Bbb R^n$ be an invertible function. Then we have clearly $id_U=f^{-1}\circ f$. Now if we calculate the total differential of $x_0 \in U$ we get $id_{\Bbb R^n}=d(id_U)(x_0)$. I don't understand why we get the identity matrix... Can someone help me? Thanks!

Added: Okay we have that $id_U$ is a linear map. So because of this we get: $$\lim_{h \to (0,\dots,0)} \frac{\|\operatorname{id}_U(x_0+h) - \operatorname{id}_U(x_0) - d(\operatorname{id}_U)(x_0)(h)\|}{\|h\|} = \frac{\|\operatorname{id}_U(h)  - d(\operatorname{id}_U)(x_0)(h)\|}{\|h\|}$$

The only way that this limit is equal to zero is that $d(id_U)(x_0)(h)=id_U(h)$ and furthermore we have that $id_U(h)=id_{\Bbb R^n}(h)$. So we conclude, that $d(id_U)(x_0)=id_{\Bbb R^n}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the identity matrix, it is the identity function in $\mathbb R^n$, and it follows from the definition: $d(\operatorname{id}_U)(x_0)$ is the unique linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$ such that
$$\lim_{h \to (0,\dots,0)} \frac{\|\operatorname{id}_U(x_0+h) - \operatorname{id}_U(x_0) - d(\operatorname{id}_U)(x_0)(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0. \tag{$*$}$$

---

*Added:* In general, if $g : U \subseteq \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, $x_0 \in U$, and $U$ contains a neighborhood of $x_0$, then we say that $g$ is **differentiable** at $x_0$ if there exists a linear map $T : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ such that
$$\lim_{h \to (0,\dots,0)} \frac{\|g(x_0+h) - g(x_0) - T(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0. \tag{$**$}$$
Then we observe that this linear map should be unique:

If $S : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is another linear map satisfying $(**)$, denote $g(x_0+h) - g(x_0)$ by $\Delta(h)$ and observe that, for $h \neq (0,\dots,0)$, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\|S(h) - T(h)\|}{\|h\|} &= \frac{\|S(h) - \Delta(h) + \Delta(h) - T(h)\|}{\|h\|} \\
&\leq \frac{\|S(h) - \Delta(h)\|}{\|h\|} + \frac{\|\Delta(h) - T(h)\|}{\|h\|}\,.
\end{align}
Thus
$$\lim_{h \to (0,\dots,0)} \frac{\|S(h) - T(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0$$
and then, for all $x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{(0,\dots,0)\}$,
$$0 = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\|S(tx) - T(tx)\|}{\|tx\|} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{|t|\|S(x) - T(x)\|}{|t|\|x\|} = \frac{\|S(x)-T(x)\|}{\|x\|}$$
meaning that $S(x) = T(x)$, and since $S(0,\dots,0) = T(0,\dots,0)$ because both are linear, $S=T$.

Once knowing that the map $T$ in the definition is unique, we denote it by $dg(x_0) : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$.

---

Returning to your question, observe that $\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^n} : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is linear and satisfies $(*)$, therefore $\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^n} = d(\operatorname{id}_U)(x_0)$ by the uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still don't get it. Why is $d(id_U)(x_0)$ a linear map and why it is unique?

Comment: I expanded my answer. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks for expanding your answer, can you please take a look at the adding in my question. I hope that it is right.

Comment: @PeterMinford That's right! Also observe that if $T : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is linear, then $dT(x_0) = T$ for all $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The total differential of a linear map is always the map itself. If $L:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R^m$ is a linear function, then

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{L(x)-L(x_0)-L(x-x_0)}{\Vert x-x_0\Vert}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{L(x-x_0-x+x_0)}{\Vert x-x_0\Vert}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{0}{\Vert x-x_0\Vert}=0.$$

So by definition, $L$ is its own derivative. $\mathrm d\operatorname{id}=\operatorname{id}$ is just a special case of this.

It's also not surprising, considering that the differential is supposed to be the closest linear approximation of a function. It would be bad if the closest linear approximation of a linear function wasn't the function itself...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So this means, that $d(id_U)(x_0)$=id_U$? But why is it linear map?

Comment: Try it out: is $\operatorname{id}(x+y)=\operatorname{id}(x)+\operatorname{id}(y)$ and $\operatorname{id}(\lambda x)=\lambda\operatorname{id}(x)$? If yes, then it's linear by definition.